# Extracting specific columns from pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I'm trying to use python to read my csv file extract specific columns to a `pandas.dataframe` and show that dataframe. However, I don't see the data frame, I receive Series([], dtype: object) as an output. Below is the code that I'm working with:
My document consists of: 
     product    sub_product issue   sub_issue   consumer_complaint_narrative
     company_public_response    company state   zipcode tags
     consumer_consent_provided  submitted_via   date_sent_to_company
     company_response_to_consumer   timely_response consumer_disputed?
     complaint_id

I want to extract :
     sub_product    issue   sub_issue   consumer_complaint_narrative

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\....\\consumer_complaints.csv")
df=df.stack(level=0)
df2 = df.filter(regex='[B-F]')
df[df2]
```

Comment: When you extract only one column that automatically becomes a `series`, do you want to forcefully make it a dataframe?

Comment: yes  want to make it a dataframe with columns B through F

Comment: You can simple use it like this: `df2 = df[['b','c','d','e','f']]` why are you using regex?

Comment: it still produces Series([], dtype: object) as output

Comment: I think you need `df=pd.read_csv("C:\\....\\consumer_complaints.csv")` and `print (df.loc[:, 'B':'F'])`.

Comment: but the best is add some sample data to answer, please check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @jezrael I've already tried that. It doesn't work. it gives an hashtable error

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

input_file = "C:\\....\\consumer_complaints.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(input_file)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
cols = [1,2,3,4]
df = df[df.columns[cols]]
```

Here specify your column numbers which you want to select. In dataframe, column start from index = 0

```
cols = []
```

You can select column by name wise also. Just use following line

```
df = df[["Column Name","Column Name2"]]
```

Comment: thank you for your help. However, I still receive the hashtable error.

Comment: df=df["product", "sub_product", "issue", "sub_issue", 
    "consumer_complaint_narrative", "complaint_id"]
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-41-9654e38dc1bf>", line 1, in <module>
    df=df["product", "sub_product", "issue", "sub_issue", "consumer_complaint_narrative", "complaint_id"]


KeyError: ('product', 'sub_product', 'issue', 'sub_issue', 'consumer_complaint_narrative', 'complaint_id')

Comment: I know it's reading the whole file and creating dataframe. The dataframe exists. It's just that I can't choose specific columns

Comment: You have to use double square bracket.

df=df[["product", "sub_product", "issue", "sub_issue", "consumer_complaint_narrative", "complaint_id"] ]

Comment: Hope above comment will solve your problem. If any other error occur. Let me know

Comment: thank you @kepy97 that worked. Why do we have to put two square brackets?

Comment: In dataframe only one bracket with one column name returns as a series. If more than one column found than it raise "Key error". So for multiple column it takes input as array.

Please [Refer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) this document for more details.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to achieve this would be as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\....\\consumer_complaints.csv")
df2 = df.loc[:,'B':'F']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry I've tried this multiple times it doesn't work. It gives hashtable error

Comment: In that case the problem may be in the data. Look at the contents of the csv file.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, using slicing:

```
df=pd.read_csv

df1=df[n1:n2]
```

Where `$n1<n2#` are both columns in the range, e.g:
if you want columns 3-5, use

```
df1=df[3:5]
```

For the first column, use

```
df1=df[0]
```

Though not sure how to select a discontinuous range of columns.

We can also use i.loc. Given data in dataset2:

dataset2.iloc[:3,[1,2]]

Will spit out the top 3 rows of columns 2-3 (Remember numbering starts at 0)

[image]

Then dataset2.iloc[:3,[1,2]] spits out

[image]